# Changes are not getting reflected in Vue Js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

I am using Laravel as backend and Vue JS in front end.
When i try to run command npm install i get this error,

```
    npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.

> node-sass@4.11.0 install C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\laravel-mix\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


> node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dreamlogic\\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.14.1 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dreamlogic\\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dreamlogic\\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dreamlogic\\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dreamlogic\\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dreamlogic\\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dreamlogic\\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\Rhugveda Desai\Anaconda3\python.EXE
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Rhugveda Desai\Anaconda3\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:295:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dreamlogic\\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\dreamlogic\dalal-spare-parts-dreamlogic\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules\laravel-mix\node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.3.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN babel-loader@7.1.5 requires a peer of webpack@2 || 3 || 4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2 requires a peer of webpack@^3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@1.7.0 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@6.0.7 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.3.0 requires a peer of webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2 requires a peer of webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@2.11.3 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-18T17_51_07_932Z-debug.log
```

My package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17",
        "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^4.0.5",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "vue-ckeditor5": "^0.4.1",
        "vue-full-calendar": "^2.7.0",
        "vue-native-notification": "^1.0.5",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.2",
        "vuetify": "^1.5.4"
    }
}
```

I tried putting some console.log statements in the component file. But they are not getting logged in the conosole. Also the alert function is not working. What could be the reason? I am new to this technology. Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of `node-sass@4.11.0` is a beta version and seem to have a problem with GitHub.

Try to upgrade to `"node-sass": "^5.0.0"` in your `package.json` and then re-run the command `npm install`.
If it don't work, please paste your entire package.json file there.

Comment: Hello thanks for commenting! Please check my package.json. @alexis-r

Comment: Hello @RhugvedaDesai for me your package.json work perfectly. Added 1565 packages in 33.691s. So if it don't work at this time, just remove your "node-modules" and your "package-lock.json" file, and then, retry the "npm install".